# Game score algorithm based on remaining time, user level, and difficulty?

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, math, game-center, game-development

I'm just wondering if anybody has any good game score algorithms based on REMAINING TIME, USER LEVEL, and DIFFICULTY.

Currently I'm using a very simply line of code that says:

```
     (100*rTime)*level*difficulty
```

The problem with this is that the range of points is too much of a difference. For example, at level 1 with a difficulty ranging b/w 1-3 and a max time of 30s the user would be getting between 100 to 9000 points.

Also, for greater levels the points returned are way too high. I want the points awarded to be higher with each level, but with the current equation, the result is too high. For example, at level 10 with a difficulty of 3 and max time of 30s, the user would be receiving between 3,000 to 90,000 points. Again, the difference in points is way too much, and the 90,000 points is way to high.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Make a table with the acceptable scores per level, then use trial-and-error to see if you can find an algorithm that seems to work? And remember, you don't _have_ to use multiplication everywhere. Sometimes division or addition might be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have factors less than 2. You can have a difficulty factor of 1 for "easy", and 1.05 for "medium" (gives 5% more points).

You can also have a logarithmic function for the time, which makes it grow slower with higher values.